# javax.ws.rs.client hostname may not be null

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, exchangewebservices

I am trying to connect to a MS Exchange Server using jax-rs and jersey to get an authentication token

```
    //Set up client configuration for proxy
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        config.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
        config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, ConfigurationUtil.getProxyURL());
        config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_USERNAME, ConfigurationUtil.getUser());
        config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_PASSWORD, ConfigurationUtil.getPassword());
        

//Set up the form
        Form form = new Form();
        form.param(OAUTH_GRANT_TYPE, OAUTH_GRANT_TYPE_VALUE);
        form.param("client_id", CLIENT_ID);
        form.param("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET);
        form.param("scope", "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All");

//Set the url and make the call
    Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient(config)
                    .target("login.microsoftonline.com")
                    .path(TENANT_NUMBER)
                    .path("oauth2")
                    .path("v2.0")
                    .path("token")
                    .request()
                    .put(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
```

And the error I get is a suprising one, because the host name shouldn't be null.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
```

Here is the full stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.vanguard.tip.ims.fis.service.EmailService.getInstance(EmailService.java:134)
at com.vanguard.tip.ims.fis.factories.ServiceFactory.createExchangeMailService(ServiceFactory.java:32)
at com.vanguard.tip.ims.fis.controller.SmartController.execute(SmartController.java:86)
at com.vanguard.tip.ims.fis.batchlauncher.SmartRunner.run(SmartRunner.java:55)
at com.vanguard.tip.ims.fis.batchlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
at org.apache.http.util.Args.containsNoBlanks(Args.java:81)
at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:80)
at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.<init>(ApacheConnector.java:259)
at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnectorProvider.getConnector(ApacheConnectorProvider.java:116)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:425)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.access$000(ClientConfig.java:90)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:122)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:119)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:340)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:733)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:135)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:105)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:101)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
at com.vanguard.tip.ims.fis.service.EmailService.getOAuthToken(EmailService.java:203)
at com.vanguard.tip.ims.fis.service.EmailService.initializeService(EmailService.java:263)
at com.vanguard.tip.ims.fis.service.EmailService.<init>(EmailService.java:109)
at com.vanguard.tip.ims.fis.service.EmailService.<init>(EmailService.java:95)
at com.vanguard.tip.ims.fis.service.EmailService$SingletonHolder.init(EmailService.java:122)
at com.vanguard.tip.ims.fis.service.EmailService$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(EmailService.java:115)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for `Client.target(String)` has to be in URI format so it should be something like

```
 .target("https://login.microsoftonline.com")
```